# Magento simple product tier pricing by percentage?

Tags: magento

This is more of a general question... Does anybody know of a hack or an existing module which will allow users to define tier prices on Simple products as a percentage rather than an actual value?

So this would be the scenario:

**Price:** £10

**Price for 2 and above:** 10%

So the new price displayed for 2 or above on the frontend would be **£11**

I found an extension which did this, but it appears to be defunct and the extension company won't reply to my emails. If someone has any experience doing this please let me know.

Comment: You should extend the base product price model. The file that you should check `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php` where available `_applyTierPrice` function.

Answer (score 0):

Adam, wouldn't the tier price be LESS than the list price on the front end?

If you intend to offer percentage discounts then check out Price Updater (formerly known as Price Templates) - you can create tiers based on percentage discount on many products at once. The tier price is saved directly to the product so the percentage discount is calculated when you save the product prices.

http://www.webshopapps.com/price-templates.html